Firebase performance monitoring does not trace my network request
package:

http: ^1.2.0

I'm using http package for my network request.
I want to implement the performance monitoring in my flutter app.
once user successfully logged in at the time firebase performance collection is enabled.
Custom traces are worked correctly but network request not captured by the firebase.
getData(query, [queryParams]) async{
  var token = await GetAndStoreLocalStorageValue().getToken();
  HttpMetric? metric;
  if(query != '<query for firebase credential>') {
    await FirebasePerformance.instance.isPerformanceCollectionEnabled();
    metric = FirebasePerformance.instance
    .newHttpMetric((url+'/'+query).toString(), HttpMethod.Get);

    await metric.start();
  }
  try {
    var response = await client.get(
      Uri.https(url, query, queryParams),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      }
    );
    return response;
  }
  catch(error) {
    return error;
  }
  finally {
    if(metric != null || query != '<query for firebase credential>') {
      print("stop");
      await metric?.stop();
    }
  }
}

Where I made mistakes?

Have you found a solution to this?

I have the same problem, does anyone have a solution?
